# required field is not showing up as required in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, updatelistitems

I have changed a field on the List item to required field of project site when I go and add new item that filed doesn't show up as required field. See Below

Can you advise why?

[image]

Comment: Do you have any content types associated with the list?

Comment: No,Content Types associated

Comment: You mean it does not have a red asterisk or that you can add the item even without filling in the field?